# The sum of fractions of square of binomial coefficient DIVIDED by index variable

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I came across the following sum to simplify and completely stuck:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{{n\choose k}^2}{k+1}$$

I know Vandermonde equation, differentiation and integration methods for binomial coefficients; however, I still don't see a way to solution.

Comment: Would you be so kind to share the approach?

Comment: One may simplify the sum of interest to $$\frac{\binom{2n+1}{n}}{n+1}=\frac{(2n+1)!}{((n+1)!)^2}$$Now use induction to prove the result.

Comment: @MarkViola. Hi Mark. *Happy New Year !*

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hi Claude my friend!  Happy New Year to you!

Comment: @outmind One more solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absorb the $k+1$ and apply Vandermonde:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\binom{n}{k}^2}{k+1}
&=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}^2\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n+1}{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n+1}{n}
\end{align}

Comment: Nicely done,  (+1)

Comment: How simple it is! I tried to absorb 1/(k+1) but for no reason didn't see that it could be done so easy.

Comment: @Rob Pratt One more solution.

Answer (score 0):

Integration of Binomial series $$(1+t)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} t^k$$
from $t=0$ to $t=x$ gives
$$\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-1}{x(n+1)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{{n \choose k}x^{k}}{k+1}. \tag{1}$$
Changing $t$ to $1/x$ in (1) we have
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^k. \tag{2}$$
Multiplying (1) and (2), we get
$$\frac{(1+x)^{2n+1}-(1+x)^{n}}{(n+1)}=x^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{{n \choose k}^2}{k+1}+x^{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n} A_k x^{k}. \tag{3}$$
The required sum is nothing but the coefficient of $x^{n+1}$ in the L.H.S. of (3).
Finally, we get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{{n \choose k}^2}{k+1}=\frac{{2n+1 \choose n}}{n+1}.$$